# "Play Movies is not yet available in your country."even though Play Movies is actually available in their region

Tags: google-play-movies

Google Play Movies is available and works on other devices in my region (UAE) except mine. The app itself gets constantly disabled automatically on its own and does so no matter how many times I re-enable it, without displaying anything else other than that annoying error.

[image: "Play Movies is not yet available in your country."]

I have tried reinstalling and clearing the cache and data of the app, I also tried VPNs and none of it has solved the issue.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You're right that [Play Movies is available on UAE](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2843119). Just to make sure, check your [Google Play country](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid). VPN won't usually work because the app doesn't only check the IP to determine the country.

Comment: Another possibility is a Google bug.  It's hard to go through a day without finding at least one.

Comment: I did, it is in UAE. I doubt it's a bug, because it keeps happening on all devices registered with my Google account, even tablets and Chromebooks.